# Private property in parent class can be accessed and re-assigned through the instance of child class in PHP but protected one can't

Tags: php, oop, visibility, private, protected

I am very confused why `$produk1->harga = 500;` can still make a change
*(or re-assign the value 500)* to `private $harga` property despite `private $harga` in `class Produk` has **PRIVATE visibility** ? `$product1` is an instance of `class Komik`.

> `$produk1 = new Komik("Naruto", "Masashi Kishimoto", "Shonen Jump", 30000, 100);`

And by `echo $produk1->harga;` **it prints out 500 and not an ERROR**. But when I change the visibility to `protected $harga` **it prints out ERROR**. How come? I don't understand. Thank you for the answers.

```
    <?php
        
        class Produk {
            public $judul = "judul",
                    $penulis = "penulis",
                    $penerbit = "penerbit";
            private $harga;
        
        
            public function __construct($judul, $penulis, $penerbit, $harga) {
                $this->judul = $judul;
                $this->penulis = $penulis;
                $this->penerbit = $penerbit;
                $this->harga = $harga;
            }
        
            public function detailInfo() {
                $str = "{$this->judul} | {$this->penulis}, {$this->penerbit} (Rp.{$this->harga})";
        
                return $str;
            }
        
        }
        
        class Komik extends Produk {
            public $jumlahHalaman = 0;
        
            public function __construct($judul, $penulis, $penerbit, $harga, $jumlahHalaman) {
        
                parent::__construct($judul, $penulis, $penerbit, $harga);
                $this->jumlahHalaman = $jumlahHalaman;
            }
        
            public function detailInfo() {
                $str = "Komik : " . parent::detailInfo() . " - {$this->jumlahHalaman} halaman.";
        
                return $str;
            }
        }
        
        
        class Game extends Produk {
        
            public $jumlahDurasi = 0;
        
            public function __construct($judul, $penulis, $penerbit, $harga, $jumlahDurasi) {
                
                parent::__construct($judul, $penulis, $penerbit, $harga);
                $this->jumlahDurasi = $jumlahDurasi;
            }
        
            public function detailInfo() {
                $str = "Game : " . parent::detailInfo() . " ~ {$this->jumlahDurasi} jam.";
        
                return $str;
            }
        }
        
        
        $produk1 = new Komik("Naruto", "Masashi Kishimoto", "Shonen Jump", 30000, 100);
        $produk2 = new Game("Uncharted", "Neil Druckmann", "Sony Computer", 250000, 5);
        
        
        echo $produk1->detailInfo();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $produk2->detailInfo();
        
        echo "<hr>";
        $produk1->harga = 500;
        echo $produk1->harga;
```

**OUTPUT** =

Komik : Naruto | Masashi Kishimoto, Shonen Jump (Rp.30000) - 100 halaman.
Game : Uncharted | Neil Druckmann, Sony Computer (Rp.250000) ~ 5 jam.

---

500

**IF `$harga` property visibility is protected**

```
    <?php
        
        class Produk {
            public $judul = "judul",
                    $penulis = "penulis",
                    $penerbit = "penerbit";
            protected $harga;
.
.
.
```

**OUTPUT** =

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Komik::$harga in ...

**Error**: Cannot access protected property Komik::$harga in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because private properties are not inherited, and when you are trying to access your private property from child class - PHP can't find it and dynamically creates new public one. See example below.
Protected properties are inherited and that's why you can't access them from other parts of code.

```
<?php

class A {
    private $property = 100;
    
    public function print() {
        echo $this->property;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

$b = new B();
$b->property = 500;
$b->print(); // 100

var_dump($b);
/* object(B)#1 (2) {
  ["property":"A":private]=>
  int(100)
  ["property"]=>
  int(500)
} */
```

Comment: Wah, really. I am kinda shocked to hear this. So, do you think it is considered more secured if we set the visibility of property or method in parent class to protected than private? What do you prefer?

Comment: It depends on your needs, @didaen. If you somehow need to access your property in a child class, then you need to make it protected.
But the best approach here is to make everything private by default and increase publicity (firstly to protected, then to public) only if there is such a need.

Comment: But if you mistakenly re-assign a private property declared in parent class using an instance of child class, it would automatically duplicate the private property as public property with the same name. Isn't that considered a big issue?

Comment: No, it's not a big issue, because in OOP world you really shouldn't access properties directly. Better to use getters and setters (as @dev_mustafa mentioned in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

Protected variable can be accessed inside child class. However, you are not accessing it inside child class rather your accessing it outside the child class.

You can access the protected member by making a `getter()` function like

```
public function getHarga()
{
    return $this->$harga;
}
```

You can see the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for visibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's kinda shocked me to find out that when there is no property found (although it is already declared but with private visibility), php makes one new public property with the axact same name. It has me to do extra care with private visibility rather than protected. Because when I wrongly call the instace's property name, php will make a new one with public visibility.